# JSON lookup returning undefined

Tags: javascript, json

here's my problem.

```
console.log(data.selectedData.value);
>> {'id':'61', 'force':'true'}
```

but when I try to do a lookup ...

```
console.log(data.selectedData.value.force);
>> undefined

console.log(data.selectedData.value['force']);
>> undefined
```

What's going on here? The above lookup is pretty standard (see here: http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp)

Comment: I'm going to guess you have some asynchronous code in your program? You might be reading `data.selectedData.value` before it is set. Try reading `force` the *very next line* after you define `data.selectedData.value` and see if it works.

Comment: As the other answers state, you need to parse the data. Are you using any sort of framework? (Dojo, jQuery, etc.?)

Comment: Please do a `console.log(typeof data.selectedData.value)` and post the result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSON is a *text string*. If you want to access properties of JavaScript object (which is represented by JSON string), JSON should be parsed:

```
var data = JSON.parse(data.selectedData.value);
console.log(data.force);
```

**Reference:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JSON

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure data.selectedData.value is a JSON Object and not a String?

if it's a string you can always do JSON.parse()

Comment: JSON is not an object by definition (if only you don't mean [object for working with JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON)).

Comment: typeof JSON == "object"
Not sure what you mean in there... but for me it is. Maybe theoretically i'm wrong, not sure

Comment: You mix up [*JavaScript Object Notation*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JSON) and [*build-in object for working with JSON*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON).

Comment: VisioN is objecting to your use of the phrase "JSON Object", not to your use of `JSON.parse`.